# Overriding System Binaries With Home Directory Binaries

Tags: linux, autoconf, openmpi

I'm trying to compile a piece of software in my home directory (OpenMPI). One of the build dependencies (autoconf) installed on my system is not the newer version asked for by the OpenMPI autogen script. I compiled and installed the newer version of autoconf in my home directory.

Is there anyway for the binary installed in my home directory to "override" the version installed on the system for my session?

I tried setting an alias which works via command line but not for the script used to generate the configure script.

Comment: Why do you ever need to run the `autogen` script? Did you get Open MPI from the SVN?

Comment: Autoconf is not a "build dependency". It may be that autoconf is necessary to generate a tarball which should be used to build the software, but that tarball does not require autoconf.  It may be correct to call autoconf a "meta-build dependency" or a "developer dependency", but it is *not* a "build dependency".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the path to the binary you want to override to your `$PATH` environment variable.
Like `PATH=/path/to/binary:$PATH ./compile`

Your added path will then be looked up first when trying to find the `compile` command. It will only be valid for that execution and will not remain after command has returned. You can use `export PATH=/path/to/binary/:$PATH` and it will be saved for that session.

**EDIT**: As Eric.J states, you can use `which compile` which will output the path to the command, just to make sure it's the right one.

Comment: Great that's done the trick thanks, I appended to PATH as opposed to prepending.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the PATH [environment variable](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-environment-variables.html) so that your home directory appears before the system directory, e.g.

> PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH

You can then use the [which](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) command to ensure the correct binary is being picked up.

Comment: Didn't notice this answer at first, thanks. That was the problem, I was putting $HOME after the system directories in PATH.